# BulkCopy List using FastMember

Tags: c#, sql, list, sqlbulkcopy, fastmember

I've done `BulkCopy of List using FastMember and Threading` for faster Performance.

Actually,I need to bulkcopy like `999999999` records and I've made an interval for every `1000000` records and `Clearing the List` to avoid `OutofMemory Exception`.

The whole process took like `16 Hours` to complete and Now,My problem is : `No records have been inserted`.While the process is going on,I've read the data using `(nolock)` and my query is showing data and sometimes it is showing `No Records`.I think the data has been inserting and deleting.

The reason,I'm saying this is : If I start inserting any record now,the Identity Column is showing very big Number in Millions.
So,as per my knowledge,I feel that records have been inserted and deleted.

My Code :

```
private void Btn_Start_Encrypting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Btn_Start_Encrypting.Enabled = false;

                Lbl_Msg1.Text = "Time Started : " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

                DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;                

                #region List<CustomClass> with Random Numbers

                Random rand = new Random();

                Thread previousThread = null;

                for (int i = 1; i <= 999999999; i++)
                {
                    LstEncData.Add(new EncryptedData { MESSAGE_ID = rand.Next(1, 100), ENCRYPTED_DATA = EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(i.ToString("D9")) });

                    if (i % 1000000 == 0)
                    {
                        LstEncData = LstEncData.OrderBy(p => p.MESSAGE_ID).ToList();

                        if (previousThread != null)
                        {
                            previousThread.Join();
                        }

                        List<EncryptedData> copyList = LstEncData.ToList();

                        previousThread = new Thread(() => BulkCopyList(copyList));
                        previousThread.Start();

                        LstEncData.Clear();
                    }
                }

                if (LstEncData.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (previousThread != null)
                    {
                        previousThread.Join();
                    }

                    List<EncryptedData> copyList = LstEncData.ToList();

                    previousThread = new Thread(() => BulkCopyList(copyList));
                    previousThread.Start();

                    LstEncData.Clear();
                }

                previousThread.Join();

                Lbl_Msg2.Text = "Time Ended : " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

                DateTime EndTime = DateTime.Now;

                TimeSpan duration = EndTime - StartTime;

                Lbl_Msg3.Text = "Total Time Taken in Seconds : " + duration.TotalSeconds.ToString();

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Btn_Start_Encrypting.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

public void BulkCopyList(List<EncryptedData> Lst)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
                {
                    using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(Lst, "ENCRYPTED_DATA"))
                    {
                        SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapEncryData = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("ENCRYPTED_DATA", "ENCRYPTED_DATA");
                        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(mapEncryData);

                        bcp.DestinationTableName = "EncryptedData1";
                        bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Did I do anything wrong near Threading (or) BulkCopy ?

Comment: One million objects is a lot to bulk insert at once.  Possibly an `OutOfMemoryException` is occurring in the `try catch` block inside the `BulkCopyList` is hiding it.  A higher bulk insert doesn't translate to faster overall performance either.  Try using 100,000.

Comment: Another possibility is that the multi-threaded bulk inserts are overlapping, causing an exception because two threads are accessing the same connection at once.

Comment: @Loathing : Is there any possibility to check whether the SQL got any errors ? May be something like `log` ?

Comment: Can you confirm no exception is occurring in the BulkCopyList method?

Comment: Actually,I started trying with `100,000` records.
I'm not sure whether the BulkCopyList method got any exception.
i will try with less records and update the result.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint in the catch of the BulkCopyList.